PHP session handler with Elasticache encryption in transit - timeouts
I'm trying to setup Memcached (or Redis) as a PHP session handler on an EC2 instance, and have created an ElastiCache Memcached "serverless" instance which forces encryption in-transit to On. I'm running PHP 8.3 on Ubuntu 24.04 and installed php8.3-memcached library (enabled).
I have the following PHP config:
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "xxxxxxx:11211"

Initially I couldn't connect at all, and it seems to be related to the encrypted connection as creating a custom unencrypted Memcached instance works. So I then setup stunnel with the following:
fips = no
setuid = root
setgid = root
pid = /var/run/stunnel4/stunnel.pid
delay = yes
options = NO_SSLv2
options = NO_SSLv3

[elasticache-memcached]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:11211
connect = xxxxxxx:11211

I can telnet to 127.0.0.1:11211 and can interact fine with the Memcached server such as using stats and storing/retrieving.
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
STAT version 1.6.22
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT curr_items 0
END

I can also use the standard Memcached library in PHP and can also connect and store/retrieve without issue in PHP.
$memcached = new Memcached('test_pool');
$memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211, 1);

echo print_r($memcached->getStats(), true);

Array ( [127.0.0.1:11211] => Array ( [version] => 1.6.22 [accepting_conns] => 1 [curr_items] => 0 ) )

But it doesn't work when using it with sessions, unless I turn off encryption. And even using stunnel, I just can't get it right. Example PHP script:
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    
    session_start();

    // Check session variable
    $_SESSION['test_session'] = 'session_value';

    print('<pre>');
    print_r($_SESSION); // Should output the session variable
    print('</pre>');

    session_write_close();
?>

And the PHP error log:
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to write session lock: A TIMEOUT OCCURRED in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to write session lock: A TIMEOUT OCCURRED in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to write session lock: A TIMEOUT OCCURRED in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to write session lock: A TIMEOUT OCCURRED in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to write session lock: A TIMEOUT OCCURRED in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to write session lock: A TIMEOUT OCCURRED in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Unable to clear session lock record in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: memcached (path: 127.0.0.1:11211) in /var/www/public_html/test.php on line 5

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Looks like I can answer my own question. I had to set memcached.sess_binary_protocol=off in the PHP memcached.ini runtime configuration file under mods-available due to using stunnel.
As noted in the PHP manual:

Use the memcached binary protocol for memcached sessions instead of the text protocol. libmemcached replicas only work if the binary mode is enabled. However, certain proxies (such as twemproxy) will only work if the binary protocol is disabled. Default is On as of libmemcached 1.0.18. Prior to libmemcached 1.0.18, the default was Off.

Hopefully that helps anyone else in the same situation.
